# How assign existing, nested objects in serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I've got Membership class which contains 3 ForeginKey fields. These FK always have to reference to already existing objects so I'm wondering how simplify *create* and *update* methods inside MembershipSerializer in order to assign these fields using only keys passed in request.

Here's MembershipSerializer class code:

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = UserSerializer(many=False)
club = ClubSerializer(many=False)
inClubRole = InClubRoleSerializer(many=False)
class Meta:
    fields=(
        'user',
        'club',
        'inClubRole',
        )

    model = Membership

def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
    user_data = User.objects.get(id=validated_data.pop('user'))
    club_data = Club.objects.get(id=validated_data.pop('club'))
    inClubRole_data = InClubRole.objects.get(id=validated_data.pop('inClubRole'))
    instance = Membership.objects.create(**validated_data)
    instance.user=user_data
    instance.club = club_data
    instance.inClubRole = inClubRole_data
    return instance
```

Since User, Club, and InClubRole models already exists I want to simplify POST and UPDATE for Membership class just by passing Primary Keys like that:

```
{
"user": 1,
"club": 1,
"inClubRole": 4
}
```

However *create* methods still expects passing every field related with User, Club and InClubRole classes. How to fix that? Or maybe there is a simplier way to handle with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the arguments directly into the `Membership.objects.create` call:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Membership.objects.create(
        **validated_data,
        user_id=validated_data.pop('user'),
        club_id=validated_data.pop('club'),
        inClubRole_id=validated_data.pop('inClubRole')
    )
```

I believe you can also get this to work by setting your fields as:

`fields=('user_id', 'club_id', 'inClubRole_id')`

and changing your JSON to:

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "club_id": 1,
  "inClubRole_id": 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works that way. However is it possible to keep Serializers functionality during _GET_ so I can fill my request with fields from Club,User, InClubRole ?

Answer (score 0):

I've already handled with it a little bit different. I swapped *...Serializer*  fields to *PrimaryKeyRelatedField* so I'm able to update and create Membership object only using IDs of related objects. I also override `to_representation(self,value)` method so on *get* reuqests I can fill related fields with nested data. Here's my final solution:

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = User.objects.all())
club = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Club.objects.all())
inClubRole = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = InClubRole.objects.all())
class Meta:
    fields=(        
        'user',
        'club',
        'inClubRole',
       )        
    model = Membership

def to_representation(self, value):
    data = super().to_representation(value)  
    user_data = UserSerializer(value.user)
    club_data = ClubSerializer(value.club)
    inClubRole_data = InClubRoleSerializer(value.inClubRole)
    data['user'] = user_data.data
    data['club'] = club_data.data
    data['inClubRole'] = inClubRole_data.data
    return data
```